# Groups generated by a binary operation on a set that contains one member of each conjugacy

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

I was recently trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $S\subset G$ be a set containing exactly one element of each conjugacy class of $G$. Prove that $S$ generates $G$.

I had the idea to have a look at the binary (conjugacy) operation defined as follows:
$$S\bullet S = \{s_1s_2s_1^{-1}\mid s_1,s_2\in S\}$$
and then construct the powers of this operation as
$$ S^n = \{s_1s_2\dots s_{n-1} s_n s_{n-1}^{-1}\dots s_1^{-1}\mid s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n\in S\}.$$
I don't think this operation is the right tool to solve the original problem, but it led me to an interesting question:

**Suppose for some $n$ it is $S\bullet S^{n} = S^{n}$. What restrictions do we have to impose on the group $G$ and/or on $S$ in order for $S^{n}=G$?**

For example, if for all $s\in S^{n}$ the inverse $s^{-1}$ is in $S^{n}$, this means that for some element $g\in S^{n}$ the following equation has to hold
$$gsg^{-1}=s^{-1}\implies gs = (gs)^{-1}$$
This means, that there exists an element of order 2 and thus the order of the group is even.

For some small-sized groups I have examined it worked, e.g. $S_3$ and the quaternion group.

The next step would then be to find the smallest $n$ for which $S^{n} = G$.

Comment: There's a problem with your equation: $gsg^{-1}=s^{-1}$ does not imply $gs=(gs)^{-1}$.

Comment: Although I think that $gsg^{-1}=s^{-1}$ for some $s,g$ in a finite group does imply the group has even order, if $s\neq 1$. It implies $g^2sg^{-2}=s$ and, since $g$ has odd order, $gsg^{-1}=s$, so $s=s^{-1}$, which implies $s$ has order $2$.

Comment: You should edit your title, as this is not what your question is about, and there has already been one (now deleted) answer trying to answer the question in the title (and at the beginning of your post).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, @verret! Do you think the title is more concise now? Could you shortly elaborate why $g$ would have to have odd order in that case?

Comment: It was a proof by contradiction. We're trying to prove the group has even order, so assume it has odd order, so every element in it has odd order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is that, if $S^n=S^{n+1}$, then $S^n=G$, with no additional assumption.

I'm going to assume that we have already answered the original question. (Somebody posted a proof earlier, but then deleted it because that didn't answer your question.) In particular, $\langle S\rangle =G$. Note that, since the group is finite, in fact every element of $G$ is a product of elements of $S$ (with no need to use inverses).

Since $G$ is finite, the sequence $(S,S^2,\ldots)$ must eventually stabilise. Let us call $T$ the set to which it stabilises. Now, elements of $T$ are obtained by taking an element $s$ of $S$, and conjugating by an element $t$ which is a product of elements of $S$. But we saw above that every element of $G$ is a product of elements of $S$, so $t$ can be any element of $G$, and $S$ covers all the conjugacy classes, so $T=G$.

Finally, it is obvious that if $S^n=S^{n+1}$, then $S^n=T$.

Note that this approach uses the answer to the original question, so it's not useful to answer that question, but it does answer your question.